# Throwing a fair die 5 times

Tags: probability

You throw a fair die 5 times.

What is the probability that the minimum of thrown numbers is 3?

I would have said that all possibilities are $6^5$ and that I have $(1*4^4)*5$ ways to get a minimum of 3. 1 because I need one 3 and 4 because I can then throw all number greater equal 3. I would take this product 5 times since the order matters.

I can't see my mistake and I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the minimum number is 3 (we allow 3 to be repeated and don't require any number be strictly larger than 3), then that almost means the same thing as **there are no 1's or 2's**.  It also means though that there is at least one 3, so it is not the case that there are no 1's, no 2's, and no 3's.

Count the number of ways of throwing the dice that have no 1's and no 2's:

> $4^5$ since there are 4 choices for each of the five dice.

Count how many of those were such that no three occurred either (i.e. min was greater than 3)

> $3^5$ of our previous choices were bad since there wasn't a 3 in them.  ($3^5$ since no 1, no 2, and no 3 implies all numbers were 4, 5, or 6., for three choices for each of the five dice.

Thus there are $4^5-3^5$ possible scenarios where you roll five dice and the minimum appearing number is a three.

Thus the probability is $\frac{4^5-3^5}{6^5}$